# Implementing tictactoe tree

Tags: c++

I`m implementing the a game tree in C++ for my tictactoe.

The idea is this: A minimax tree can have any number of children, depending on the game situation. The levels of the tree are commonly referred to as plies. At each ply, the opportunity to play (the "turn") switches to the other player.

Now important: The tree starts with a current board position as it`s root node. So each tree node consists of a list. The possible moves (from the computer`s point of view) are the members of that list.

My question is, how could I build that tree? Obviously, the current board state must be defined somehow, so that evaluation function knows where to start searching.

```
Struct node 
{
    Node* successors

    // get available movecount
    int count() 
    {               
        for (int count=0; count< free cells) 
            ++count 
    }

    Node* curr_board_state= root;
}

Node * root(Board b, int depth)
{
    node.successorCount = int count();
    node.value      = board.GetValue;
    if (depth > 0 && node.childCount > 0)
    {
        node.children = new Node * node.SuccessorCount;
        for (int i = 0; i <= node.SuccessorCount; ++i)
            node.Successor[i] = CreateTree(board.Move(i), depth - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        node.children = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}
```

There is some ideas. Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://github.com/gosom/tic-tac-toe-gametree/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: you will find helpful optimization techniques if you search for alpha-beta-cutoff

Answer (score 1):

For tic-tac-toe, each node in the game tree can have at most 9 children, as there are at most 9 possible moves. To my understanding, it would be an unusual approach to explicitly represent the entire game tree to evaluate it. A more straightforward approach would be to have the game board represented. When searching the game tree, nodes are evaluated by actually changing the board state, doing the evaluation and then undoing the hypothetical move again. What you describe as your approach is the basic version of the [Minimax algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), which exactly corresponds to hypothetically performing the move to be evaluated, continuing in a recursive manner, where at each level of the tree the perspective of the players is exchanged.

Answer (score 0):

"Nodes are evaluated by actually changing the board state, doing the evaluation and then undoing the hypothetical move again".

With the above in mind, couldn`t I do something like

```
int availableMoves(vector<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >& v) const {
//clear result vector.
v.clear();
//check if the game is in progress.
int state = evaluateState();
if(state != IN_PROGRESS)
return state;

//if the game is in progress, check for empty cells.
for(unsigned int x = 0; x < 3; i++)
for(unsigned int y = 0; y < 3; j++)
if(board(x,y) = free;)
v.push_back(pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(x, y));
return IN_PROGRESS;
}

Struct node

{
  node * availalableMoves;  
}

node * CreateTree(Board b, int depth)
{

vector<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > availableMoves;

// Allocate new space for nodes to be evaluated

unsigned int numAvailableMoves = (unsigned int)availableMoves.size();
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numAvailableMoves; i++) {

Stack<occupiedMoves.size();>my_free_store;

void* pv1= my_free_store.get();
int* buffer = static_cast<int*>(pv1);
void* pv2= my_free_store.get(sizeof(availableMoves));
availableMoves* pconn= new(pv2) availableMoves(incoming,outcoming,buffer);
```

My negamax algorithm is as follows:

```
int Search(int depth)
{
int score;
int x,y;
int bestScore = -2;
bool bestMove = false;
if(depth == 0) return Evaluate();
for (int turns = 0; turns < 9; ++turns) { // loop over turns
while (occupied(x,y));
make_move(x, y);
score = -Search(depth-1); // recursion
unMake();
if(score > bestScore) {
bestScore = score;
bestMove = (x,y);
}
}
return bestScore;
return bestMove;
}
```

The question is what evaluate() should contain